# Setting source in the second time (MediaElement)

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, mediaelement

In windows phone 7 ..when using the element mediaelement.

I set the source of the mediaelement using url as follows at each time the user clicks on a button:

```
myMediaElement.Source = new Uri(url, UriKind.Absolute);
```

then I play it.

when the user clicks the second time on a button .. the mediaElement doesn't work..
Why?

Comment: was it solved, i am also facing the same issue

Answer (score 3):

You can try

```
   myMediaElement.Stop();
   myMediaElement.Source = null; 
   myMediaElement.Source = new Uri(url, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
```

But I am not sure what you are upto until you post some code of what you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

Use AutoPlay to stop Automatic play

```
        myMediaElement.Source = new Uri("Your Url", UriKind.Absolute);

        myMediaElement.AutoPlay = false;
```

Now Perform play() on click